40mm grey water through cavity, fall or level?
As per the title. Should I add a slight fall when drilling through the wall. Looked on youtube and both seem to be normal. the pipe is the outlet for sink, dishwasher, washing machine. I have seen 92.5 degree bends so assume I would us this if I was to drill with a fall?
Also is the a minimum height/length for the outside pipe from the hole I drill down to the bottle gulley?
thank you.

Most horizontal pipes should have a minimum of 1/8 inch slope per foot, so stuff in the water flows down and does not collect.

What is a "bottle gulley"? Local slang for something, unclear what.

If you're putting a 2 inch pipe through an 8 inch wall, you would have to drill an exactly 2 inch hole with less than 1/32 inch clearance in order to prevent the pipe from sloping appropriately, and if you try to drill at the suitable angle you'd have to leave less than 1/32" clearance to prevent the pipe from being  installed too horizontally.

All drain pipes need a minimum slope. For typical household drain pipe sizes that's 1/4" per foot, or roughly 2% grade (so 2cm/100cm.)

If you can drill to allow a slight fall that would be better than a level hole through the wall.
As others stated a 1/4" drop per foot is preferred.
